# Debugging Win32 API Apps for Memory Leaks

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks

I was reading up on how to go about finding memory leaks with the C++ `new` operator and the standard CRT `malloc` function on a Win32 application.

I added some stuff for working with windows sockets and I wanted to include `crtdbg.h` only if running in debug mode, along with some other defines.  So I ended up piecing this together into my `stdafx.cpp` as my standard pre-compiled header:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Windows Sockets
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")


// If running in debug mode we need to use this library to check for memory leaks, output will be in DEBGUG -> WINDOWS -> OUTPUT
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx
#ifdef _DEBUG   
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718758/using-crtdumpmemoryleaks-to-display-data-to-console
    #ifndef DBG_NEW      
        #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )      
        #define new DBG_NEW   
    #endif
    #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
    #include <crtdbg.h>
#endif  // _DEBUG
```

I also intended to put these lines just before the exit point of my program:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG  
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); 
#endif
```

Anyways, it appears to compile but I get some strange warning:

> warning C4005: '_malloca': macro redefinition

From the `crtdbg.h`.  Is this due to the wrong ordering of the headers in the `stdafx.h`, or is this normal?  Also, am I on the right track for detecting memory leaks in Win32 apps or is there something else I should be using in Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe you should define `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` before you include your first header file (or at least, before Windows.h).

Comment: You might be interested in [VLD](http://vld.codeplex.com/) (visual leak detector)

Answer (score 2):

> From the crtdbg.h. Is this due to the wrong ordering of the headers in the stdafx.h, or is this normal?

Perhaps [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx) can help you. Notice this part :

**For the CRT functions to work correctly, the #include statements must follow the order shown here.**

---

You could use [*Visual Leak Detector*](http://vld.codeplex.com/) for finding leaks involved with missing `delete` for `new` operator as others mentioned. I had good experience with it, but I usually tend to triple-check if in my code every `new` has corresponding `delete` call.

---

> Also, am I on the right track for detecting memory leaks in Win32 apps or is there something else I should be using in Visual Studio?

The other type of memory leaks are `GDI leaks`. These usually happen when you do not restore the [`device context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into original state or you forget to delete the `GDI object`.

For those leaks I use [*GDIView*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html). Its usage is well described but if you have any questions leave a comment.

You might find [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak.aspx) useful.

Of course, there are lots of good tools out there, this is just my suggestion.

Hopefully this helps.

Best regards.

Comment: First part is indeed the right thing to do. I have the same problem, corrected today when I realize that stdlib.h was included twice, and first time without having first defined _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC. So the three lines written in MSDN have to be written in the indicated order, and before all other include if possible (avoiding possible hidden include of stdlib).